# JavaScript Add/Remove sequential divs (add/remove/insert/re-order steps)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, html

I currently have javascript/jquery to 'add and remove' steps from a set of instructions dynamically created in divs.

```
    function add(){ 
        var id = document.getElementById("hiddenCount").value;  
        $("#myId").append("<div id='step"+ 'id' + "...onclick='delete('"+id+")"...);
        id = (id -1) + 2;
        document.getElementById("hiddenCount").value = id;
    }
    function delete(id){
        $("#" +id).remove();
        document.getElementById("hiddenCount").value = (id-1);
    }
```

This is great for adding and removing NON-sequenced/ordered ids, but if I want to insert a step in between 2 other steps or, remove several steps and then add, the numbering of ids becomes very unordered.  Do you know of any javascript that handles situations like this, or should I use some other method to do this, like sortable values, or ordered lists?

The overall goal is to create a very easily editable way to add/remove/insert/re-order instructions dynamically with sequential div tags using jquery/javascript.  In some cases the steps are pre-populated (from a database) and displayed, and will need to be edited.  In some cases there are NO steps at all, but they need to create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use unordered lists, that way you can base the step's ordering not on their id's or something else, but on their index inside the parent `ul`. If you'd like a code example I wouldn't mind writing one up.

Comment: No code sample needed, I have hacked something together that re-orders the steps in the accordion on update of the accordion using the 'update:' parameter of the .sortable() function.  It seems the verison of jquery I am using doesn't handle serialize very well.